# Ubuntu 16.04 64bit works slow and freezes at time?

Tags: 16.04

I have installed fresh **Ubuntu 16.04 x64** in **Dell optiplex 360**

```
    Configuration :
    Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7400@2.80Ghz
    RAM :3GB RAM
    HDD:80HDD
    Display : 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
```

When i start the pc it works completely fine after an hour it slows down and freezes sometimes then the screen goes black and again resume automatically for which i have to wait.Opening new tab or clicking on new tab in Google chrome or Firefox freezes the mouse pointer and goes black and resumes after sometime.Mouse pointer lags while moving and switching to different window hangs after clicking.

I use netbeans,filezilla,Google Chrome,Firefox etc and the `swap memory is 2GB`.
Please help me in finding solutions 
Thank you.

Comment: did you try to check your process to see what exactly consume your memory you can do by running
#ps axjf or #ps aux for more help check ps --help you can install packages to check more details like htop or atop

Comment: I checked `#ps aux` everything looks fine and also did `#top` `#free -g`.

Comment: what package you are using to consume power?

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2l4mbG3aWZaSm9PTlh6R3A0cTQ

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2l4mbG3aWZaVnFTSFlIY0MwU1E

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2l4mbG3aWZac2N1WTR5RkVqMkU


check the above links for screenshots i have taken.

Comment: can you post screenshots here

Comment: i have just installed powertop on my system.

Comment: did you try tlp its good power manager

Comment: i think tlp is useful for laptops . I installed powertop but still it hangs sometimes i dont think its an power management issue .

Comment: check the process to see if there is process consume high cpu usage or high memory usage install htop or atop by running #sudo apt-get install htop or #sudo apt-get install atop and for running use run #htop #atop you can use too this command #top -s and try to see which process is fillup the cpu or memory

Comment: I think after installing powertop the pc is working better.

Comment: All the desktop runninf ubuntu 16.04 has become slow .